# OData Routing with EF6 Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework, odata, asp.net-web-api

I've written a Web API 2 with OData in VB.Net using EF6 against a SQL Azure DB - and all is working quite well.  Now I need to add another controller that returns a set of records using a stored procedure that is passed an ID.  I am using the Database First option of EF 6 so I created the Stored Proc in SQL and imported into my EF model.  The data returned does not match any of the existing entities so it returns the complex type created by the EF update tool.

I created the OData controller using the VS 2013 scaffolding with a single Get action that accepts the ID and returns the stored procedure's set of records.  I also added the controller name to the ODataConventionModelBuilder for setting up the routes.  When I try to call the Controller(ID) it returns this error.

```
{
"odata.error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": {
        "lang": "en-US",
        "value": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:54146/odata/UnMappedIOTags1(441)'."
    },
    "innererror": {
        "message": "No routing convention was found to select an action for the OData path with template '~/entityset/key'.",
        "type": "",
        "stacktrace": ""
    }
}
```

}

My WebApiConfig.vb contains the following:

```
    Dim builder As New ODataConventionModelBuilder
    '...  12 other entries removed for brevity
    builder.EntitySet(Of IO)("IOs")
    builder.EntitySet(Of mapUnMappedTags_Result)("UnMappedIOTags1")

    config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute(
                routeName:="odata",
                routePrefix:="odata",
                model:=builder.GetEdmModel(),
                batchHandler:=New DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer))
```

And my controller looks like this.

```
 Public Class UnMappedIOTags1Controller
    Inherits ODataController
    Private db As New AppasEntities

    <ResponseType(GetType(mapUnMappedTags_Result))> <EnableQuery>
    Function GetUnMappedIOTags1(<FromODataUri> key As Integer) As IQueryable(Of mapUnMappedTags_Result)

        Return db.mapUnMappedTags(key).AsQueryable

    End Function
End Class
```

I have it working in a Web API controller that doesn't use OData routing but I prefer to implement as an OData controller like the other 14 OData controllers in the project.

What am I missing?